# Why do pipes have a limited capacity?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I've read that pipes need to have a limited capacity. But I don't understand why. What happens if a process writes into a pipe without a limit?

Answer (score 9):

It's due to buffering. Pipes are not "magical", pipes do not ensure all processes process each individual byte or character in lockstep. Instead pipes buffer inter-process output and then pass the buffer along. And this buffer size limit is what you're referring to. [In many Linux distros and in macOS the buffer size is 64KiB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer).

Imagine there's a process that outputs 1GB of data every second to stdout - and it's piped to another process that can only process 100 bytes of data every minute on stdin - consider that those gigabytes of data have to go somewhere. If there was an infinitely sized buffer than you would quickly fill up the memory-space of whatever OS component owns the pipe and then start paging out to disk - and then your pagefile on disk would fill up - and that's not good.

By having maximum buffer sizes, the output process will be notified when it's filled the buffer and it's free to handle that event however is appropriate (e.g. by pausing output if it's a random number generator, by dropping data if it's a network monitor, by crashing, etc).

Comment: Historically, the pipe buffer size was often 5 KiB; POSIX mandates a minimum pipe buffer size of 4 KiB.  Originally, machines had less than one megabyte of memory in total (and not much more disk space); they could not afford to store everything.  The buffer size was an effective rate-limiting mechanism (it still is).

Comment: "the output process will be notified" can be misinterpreted as saying that some sort of signal like SIGPIPE gets delivered to the outputting process. Wouldn't it better instead to say [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) will behave differently under different circumstances as described under PIPE_BUF section [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)?

Answer (score 8):

Internal mechanisms aside, I suspect the root issue behind the question is one of terminology.  Pipes have limited *capacity*, but unlimited overall volume of data transferred.

The analogy to a piece of physical plumbing is pretty good: a given piece of water pipe has a characteristic internal volume defined by its length, its shape, and the cross section of its interior.  At any given time, it cannot hold any more water than fits in that volume, so if you close a valve at its downstream end then water eventually (maybe immediately) stops flowing into its other end because all the available space within -- the pipe's capacity -- is full.  Until and unless the pipe is *permanently* closed, however, there is no bound on how much water may be able traverse it over its lifetime.