# What is the reason for writing the value of c again outside the loop and how are multiple values of c stored in one pipe?

Tags: c

```
printf("Enter any alphabetical character or digit [type ; to end]:");
do{ 
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if(c>='0' && c<='9')
             write(RD[1],&c,1);
    if((c>='a' && c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z') )
             write(RA[1],&c,1);
}while(c!=';');

write(RD[1],&c,1);
write(RA[1],&c,1);
```

The values of c are already written to the pipes in the loop. Why did we write them again outside the loop?

Also, how are multiple values of c stored over and over again in one pipe?

Comment: Perhaps whatever is reading them expects a trailing `;`.

Answer (score 1):

> The values of c are already written to the pipes in the loop.

No, it's not.

When `c` is `;` the conditions in the loop are false so nothing is written in the loop.

```
c = ';' --> c>='0' && c<='9' is false, i.e. no write
c = ';' --> (c>='a' && c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z') is false, i.e. no write
```

So the ; is only written once - after the loop

> Also, how are multiple values of c stored over and over again in one pipe?

Well, I'm not an expert in pipes but I assume they have some buffer capacity. Maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/a/59554475/4386427 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Answer (score 0):

The loop breaks when c is ';'. And for that case, it is not written to the pipes. The reader is expecting the ending ';' so it is written to both pipes after the loop.